# Printer-friendly versions?

Tags: support, export

When I print an MO thread (using Chrome, at least), the font size is extremely small (8pt? nested indices are very hard to read, at least). Since I don't think this is easily fixable on the user side (at least not without MathJax getting all messed up), could we have a "printer-friendly" option or an export to PDF? (Of course, a script that would transform markup to LaTeX would be gold standard, but I'm not asking that much.)

Comment: You could try if the output of [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/) works well enough.

Comment: Thank you! That's a very useful service. (Considering my question answered, unless anyone wants to build a PDF exporter...)

Comment: I use Unix/Linux command `import' to make a jpeg of the screen. Before that, I use control+ to enlarge the piece i want. The main downside is the limited amount of material per jpeg. Good for quick documentation in any case.

Comment: These comments seem like pretty fine answers to me...

Comment: Nested indices are usually hard to read, and often deter me from making sense of a question. Better typesetting would get more answers!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) is often useful for such purposes.

This tool is very frequently mentioned in several other posts on this topic, sometimes various other tools are mentioned too:

- [Printing out Stack Overflow/Exchange Q&As including comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22877) on Meta Stack Exchange
- [Save the answer in PDF?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15163) on Mathematics Meta
- There are some bookmarklets created by the user NormalHuman, see: [Save the answer in TEX?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15230) or [Save the answer in TeX/PDF - revisioned](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25175). As mentioned in those posts, some of the links stopped working at some point in the past (so you might save the bookmarklet if you want to use them). Here is a link which seems to be working at the moment  [Save a question and answers as LaTeX](https://normalhuman.github.io/savetex/) ([github](https://github.com/normalhuman/normalhuman.github.io/tree/master/savetex)). (I will just mention that there are some [other bookmarklets](https://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/) created by the same user that might be useful for people using Stack Exchange sites. You can find source code also [on github](https://github.com/normalhuman/normalhuman.github.io/tree/master/stackmarklets).)

Comment: The question was basically answered in the comments. (Although I have mentioned some other solution. Basically, I repeated the same advice I have [previously given in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2018/12/10).) I suppose that many users might ask about this, so it's probably better to have at least some answer - not just comments.