# Question regarding the StackPrinter site

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, stackexchange, export

Does anybody here know whatever happened to the StackPrinter site? It seems to me that it is not working anymore. Do you know of a currently working version/link of the site?

Please let me thank you in advance for your attentive replies.

Comment: It seems to be working now. What exactly was the problem at the time of the post? For people unfamiliar with StackPrinter, I'll add that this website is mentioned here: [Printer-friendly versions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/505) For example, this is what I get for this question: http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=4594&service=meta.mathoverflow

Comment: As a site not, ([meta-tag:export]) seems like a suitable tag here. But since all five spotes are already used, I was not sure which of the used tags to replace (if any).

Comment: Maybe somebody else can can confirm whether they can access the site. I have also checked [Down for Everyone or Just Me](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/stackprinter.com), which says that StackPrinter is up.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I suppose there is something wrong with my connection... I can't still access the site: Chrome is my default browser and I get an "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" message after any attempt I make to enter it. Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: It seems to be working fine today!